# How can i setup Tortoise svn externals?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a project which currently resides in svn. I want to start to use externals .
I am a bit confused on where to start and the reason behind it all.
How can i start to setup externals and what it means ?
I have the project in svn. Now there are about 30 projects and each project may depend on others when i check dependencies in Visual Studio

How do i start to set this up in svn ?

If possible a step by step process would be great.

Comment: The free PDF [SVN book](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.pdf) covers this in quite some detail, which includes the step-by-step process you ask about.

Comment: I have seen the book, but what i need is a more basic step by step guide , like 1. "go to svn do this"  2. "go to your checked out version and do this " etc ?

Comment: That's in the book. SO is not a *write me a tutorial* site. If you follow the examples in the book, it walks you through everything.

Comment: I assume your speaking about the heading Externals Definitions
 in the book ? If so , i have looked at it , quite confusing

Comment: Your question sounds as if project inter-dependencies were an issue as well. It's impossible to say without knowing your project but maybe thinking about a clean way of organizing your projects will also give you some hints on what to add as an external and where.

Comment: Your question's title indicates you use TortoiseSVN. I added the tag. Maybe you'll find their [docs on externals](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html) helpful.